# With iOS layout contraints is it possible to collapse padding between labels when height is 0?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Consider a view that contains three `UILabel`s with vertical contraints defined as follows:

```
[self.view
 addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                 constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[label1]-2-[label2]-2-[label3]"
                 options:0
                 metrics:nil
                 views:views]];
```

This will product a layout with the labels stacked vertically w/ 2px padding between each label.

In my app, sometimes the text displayed on one or more of the labels is nil (or blank) which means the label frame ends up with height == 0. In this case, I want the 2px padding between the 0 height label to be collapsed.

When all labels have a text value, I want the layout to be:

label1 text
[2px]
label2 text
[2px]
label3 text

When `label2` has a nil text value, I want the layout to be:

label1 text
[2px]
label3 text

In the latter case, label 2 is actually still there but has 0 height and its 2px padding has been collapsed.

**Question**: Is this possible? How would I define constraints to accomplish this?

## EDIT

I realize it is possible to implement the padding (edge inset) in a subclass of `UILabel` and take the padding out of the constraints. I may go that route, just hoping that there is a way to define collapsing this padding in the constraint definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redefine your constraints when the values you are displaying in your labels changes.

If this is a view subclass with three string properties, in the setter of each property, you can call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`.

Then, in your `updateConstraints` implementation, remove the constraints previously created (which you can store in a property if required, since the VFL method returns an array) and regenerate the appropriate ones.

If you are in a view controller which is handling the layout, there is an analagous method for updating the constraints on the view controller's view: `updateViewConstraints`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do this, and you should deal with this by modifying your constraints instead of messing with a `UILabel` subclass. However, it's kind of tricky to do using VFL as you are currently doing though, because what you need to do is hold a reference to the individual constraints between each label, and VFL returns an array of constraints (so you won't know which is which).

So, assuming you're not using VFL, you'll want to create the constraints between each pair of labels individually and store it in an ivar or property:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *label1To2Constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWith...];
NSLayoutConstraint *label2To3Constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWith...];
```

If you **don't** explicitly add constraints to set a fixed height on the labels (the VFL code you're using doesn't do this), then if the label has no text in it, it will shrink to zero height. So now all you need to do is after updating the text for the labels, do some checks on whether the labels have text or not and update the `constant` property of the constraint between each pair as needed:

```
BOOL hasLabel1Text = label1.text.length > 0;
BOOL hasLabel2Text = label2.text.length > 0;
BOOL hasLabel3Text = label3.text.length > 0;
label1To2Constraint.constant = (hasLabel1Text && hasLabel2Text) ? 2.0f : 0.0f;
label2To3Constraint.constant = (hasLabel2Text && hasLabel3Text) ? 2.0f : 0.0f;
```

Changing the `constant` of existing constraints can (and should) be done **without** removing and re-adding the constraint. It's very efficient. (Removing and re-adding constraints is much more taxing on the internal Auto Layout engine, and should be avoided as much as possible.)

In order to save you some pain, I'd like to point you towards the [`UIView+AutoLayout` category](https://github.com/smileyborg/UIView-AutoLayout) I've created. I promise it will dramatically improve your experience with Auto Layout using the thinnest layer of third party code possible. You'll see that it's very easy to create the constraints you need for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This works well for this kind of problem:
https://github.com/depth42/AutolayoutExtensions